# what is Image Processing?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, image-processing

I am going to Create an application where user can edit their pictures like color balance effect, gray sheet effect, invert effect , red eye fix etc.

My application will be quite resemble to Acdsee Software.
So i wanna know that can My application be called image Processing software ?

In my point of view Image Proccessing means playing with image's enhancing the image's.

Thanks In Advance

Answer (score 3):

> In electrical engineering and computer science, image processing is any form of signal processing for which the input is an image, such as a photograph or video frame; the output of image processing may be either an image or, a set of characteristics or parameters related to the image. Most image-processing techniques involve treating the image as a two-dimensional signal and applying standard signal-processing techniques to it.[1]

So, I think you can call your software a Image Processing Software, once it check what this definition propose.

[1] http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Image_processing

Answer (score 1):

Yes, an application that does color balance, gray sheet effect, invert and red-eye fix, can reasonably be called image processing software. In fact, even a single one of those I would already call an image-processing algorithm.